# get the third cell in a table jQuery

Tags: jquery

I thought I had a decent handle on this, but apparently not. So here we go again. I want the value of the cell two spaces over from where I click. It would be the 3rd column of the row. Here is some code to understand.

I create the table like this

**php**

```
$project_info = $db->prepare("
    SELECT  projects.id,
        projects.project_name,                  
        projects.pm,    
        // ...more columns   
    FROM projects
    WHERE account_id = ?                        
"); 

$project_info->bindValue(1, $aid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$project_info->execute();       

echo "<table class='projects_contentTable'>";
echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "" . "</th>";
echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "" . "</th>";
echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Job #" . "</th>";
// ...more headers   

while ($row = $project_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {             
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<img src='images/edit.png' class='edit_project_record'/>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<img src='images/view.png' class='view_project_record'/>" . "</td>";              
    echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<a href='#'>" . $row['id'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
    // ...more td's
    echo "</tr>";               
}
echo "</table>";
```

and this code to get the value from the cell

**jquery**

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit_project_record', function() {
    pid = $(this).parent().find('td:eq(3)').text();
    alert(pid); 
    loadEditProject();
});
```

Now when the alert fires it has nothing inside the dialog box. So I am not grabbing a value from the correct cell. I've tried to break this down logically, but I am stuck. Here is my understanding, which is **obviously** wrong

1. $(this) = the image, inside 'td' element.
2. parent() = the actual 'td' element holding the image
3. find('td:eq(3)') = find a specfic 'td' from the parent location, in this case the third column of the row.
4. .text() = the text value of the selected cell

Please explain to me where my logic is broken so I can fix this. Thank you

Comment: Did you just want the 3rd column every time or the cell 2 columns over from where you clicked? Look at the answers below carefully. Most of them are just selecting the 3rd column regardless of where the click occurs.

Comment: @DevlshOne yes exactly, and I do not want just any 3rd column. I want the 3rd column in the row the click occurs. I also do not want the :nth-child(x) value as that would return all values from the column. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things:

1. `:eq()` is zero-based, so you need `td:eq(2)`.
2. `$(this)` is the image, so `$(this).parent()` is the `td`. `find()` searches descendants, and there are no `td`s within the `td` you have selected.

So you need this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
```

`closest()` starts at the current element and traverses up the DOM until it finds an element matching the selector. From the parent `tr`, you can `find` the `td`s.

Fiddle, with div instead of image: http://jsfiddle.net/bAz8P/

Comment: thanks Jason, this worked like a charm and the explanation was exactly what I needed so I *hopefully* don't have to ask anymore questions like this. +1 and answer accepted

Answer (score 4):

Take into account that `eq` is zero based so if you want to get the third column, you'll need to use `eq(2)`

```
pid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
```

As others answers already pointed out, parent won't give you the row as `this` parent is the `td`. You could use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: yea, I saw jasons answer. It's exactly what I needed with the explanation I needed. Thank you so much. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want the cell 2 cells to the right of the one you've clicked...

```
$('.projects_contentTable').on('click', 'td img', function() {
    var myTD = $('td').index(this);
    var pid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(myTD + 2)').text();
    alert(pid);
    loadEditProject();
 });
```

Comment: so I just noticed your comment up top. Would this mean that Jason's answer would not produce the same result? Because it currently is giving me the value I want. Same as yours

Comment: Jason's answer is fine because his script only triggers when you click on the class `edit_project_record`, which is the first column of cells. So, when it returns the 3rd column, it's doing the right thing. My answer can be used for any cell because it's not triggered by a specific class, just by the `img` inside the `td`. Therefore, it could be an `img` in the 16th cell and it would return the text of the 18th cell. LOL.. you follow that?

Comment: actually yea, that's an awesome explanation. Thanks a ton

Comment: I do have one more question, does this work in reverse as well. As in say the image is in the 13th cell, if you were to put `('td:eq(myTD - 2)')` would it return the value of the 11th cell?

Comment: Yes, it sure would but you'd need to check and make sure that `myTD > 2` before you do it. I don't think that method would be happy with negative numbers. :)

Comment: lol, indeed. Thanks again my friend. You were an excellent resource on something I will end up using over and over

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.closest()` to find the row and then find the cell (0 based on `eq`):

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit_project_record', function() {
    pid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
    alert(pid); 
    loadEditProject();
});
```

Comment: thank you for the help +1 for another correct way of doing it